# Optical properties without LOPTICS tag

Tags: vasp, 2d-lattice, optical-properties

I have performed some calculations for a 2D-monolayer using `VASP`.
I run DOS calculations without `LOPTICS = .TRUE.`
I found that when I run the `vaspkit`, I got the files for optical properties.
Could someone please explain to me, if we are getting the files for optical properties, then how reliable are these files?

**INCAR**

```
ISTART   = 1
# ICHARG   = 11
# ISYM = 0
 PREC     = Accurate
 ENCUT    = 550
 ISMEAR   = 0
 SIGMA    = 0.1
 LREAL    = .FALSE.
 LWAVE    = .TRUE.  
 LCHARG   = .TRUE.   
 ADDGRID  = .TRUE.  
 EDIFF   = 1e-6
 EDIFFG  = -0.02
 NSW     = 0
  LORBIT  = 12
  NEDOS   = 5000
  LHFCALC= T
  AEXX   =  0.25 HFSCREEN= 0.2  
  ALGO   =  ALL
  TIME   =  0.4
```

Comment: The comment discussion has been moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58998824#58998824)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- When you open the `LHFCALC` tag, the DFT hybrid functional type dielectric function is calculated. All the output files you obtain are calculated by `VASPKIT` using this dielectric function.
- https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#optic-properties

> Could someone please explain to me, if we are getting the files for optical properties, then how reliable are these files?

- For 2D materials, these results cannot be believed. You should use the GW+BSE method to obtain reliable results. See this post for more information: [How to start with the optical properties of 2D materials with the VASP code?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/how-to-start-with-the-optical-properties-of-2d-materials-with-the-vasp-code)